# Chrome automatically refresh page after XMLHttpRequest

Tags: javascript, html, django, google-chrome

I have some strange problem with Google Chrome. I build a search field for my website. Therefor i have implemented some JS to get and process the results (see below). The problem is, when I first enter the page with chrome and using the search with "Enter-key", chrome does the following (request from my server):

```
[10/Nov/2017 10:00:56] "GET /app/student/home/ HTTP/1.1" 200 7372 (entering the page)
[10/Nov/2017 10:00:59] "GET /api/searchCourse/daf/ HTTP/1.1" 200 95 (search request)
[10/Nov/2017 10:00:59] "GET /app/student/home/? HTTP/1.1" 200 737 (reloading -but why?? )
```

One Firefox (also with "Enterkey") or **Chrome using the "Search-button"**  it looks different, like that.

```
[10/Nov/2017 10:00:59] "GET /api/searchCourse/daf/ HTTP/1.1" 200 95 (entering the page)
[10/Nov/2017 10:00:59] "GET /app/student/home/? HTTP/1.1" 200 737 (search request)
```

I also tried debugging this Problem with Chrome, but than it behaves like it should. Also I have to add, this happens only when I first enter the page after login. When I refresh the page it works good. Can some explain this behavior?

My JS-Code:

```
var btnSearch = document.querySelector('.search').addEventListener('click', searchCourse);
var txtFieldSearch = document.getElementById('searchField').addEventListener('keydown',                 
    function (e) {
        var key = e.which || e.keyCode;
        if (key === 13) {
            searchCourse();
        }
    }
);

function searchCourse() {
    document.querySelector('.my-node').style.display = 'none';
    var input = document.getElementById('searchField').value;
    var url = '/api/searchCourse/';

    if (input.length < 3) {
        showSearchWarining('Please enter more than 3 letters.');
        return;
    }

    var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xhr.open('GET', url + input, true);
    xhr.onload = function (e) {
        if (xhr.readyState === 4) {
            if (xhr.status === 200) {
                console.log(xhr.responseText);
                addResults(xhr.responseText);
            } else {
                console.error(xhr.statusText);
            }
        }
    };
    xhr.onerror = function (e) {
        console.error(xhr.statusText);
    };
    xhr.send(null);
}
```

Comment: It looks like Chrome is submitting the buttons form when enter key is pressed - did you try event.preventDefault() in the click handler or in a form submit handler?

Comment: Hi again, sry my fault. Thanks to you Joschi it does work. But can you explain what event.preventDefault() does? Didn't get the explanation from Mozilla.

Comment: @Joschi, if you like, post that as solution so I can mark that as solution

Comment: Ok did that and added a link to mdn docs for preventDefault(). It basically prevents the default browser behaviour for an event.

Comment: OK it block default event handling, but why doesn't it only work on chrome? With Firefox it was working good.

Comment: The browsers have different default behaviors when button(s) are clicked in a form. Some treat them as a submit input if only one is present.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like Chrome is submitting the form - did you try [event.preventDefault()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event/preventDefault) in the click handler or a form submit handler to prevent further event handling from getting invoked?